# Putting a string array in ArrayAdapter inside onResponse method of JSONObject gives "No suitable Constructor" error

Tags: android, android-volley, android-arrayadapter

I am fetching some data from MySQL database using `Volley library` and putting it inside a spinner whose id is "city_spinner". I have an `Activity` called **MainActivity**, and a fragment called bookings. The spinner resides inside the fragment "bookings". The code for "bookings.java" is given below:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    final RelativeLayout ld = (RelativeLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.loader);
    final RelativeLayout fb = (RelativeLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.form_body);
    final Spinner city_sp = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.city_sp);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, dataUrl, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try{
                JSONArray city = response.getJSONArray("city");
                //I'll eventually put data from JSON into spinner, but even with String array it doesn't work.
                String[] cities = new String[]{
                        "Select a City",
                        "City1",
                        "City2",
                        "City3"
                };
                //Gives me error in line below
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this,R.layout.my_spinner, cities
                );
                spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner);
                city_sp.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

**I get the error as:**

```
Error:(151, 64) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(anonymous Listener< JSONObject>>,int,String[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; < anonymous Listener< JSONObject>> cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous Listener< JSONObject>> cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List< String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; < anonymous Listener< JSONObject>> cannot be converted to Context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that line to below

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),R.layout.my_spinner, cities
                );
```

also replace `(String)null` with just `null` in parameters of `JsonObjectRequest`

Comment: Glad I could help :) Happy Coding !